# sql server 2005 Permissions with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I  installed SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express. When I login to the Database server  using Windows Authentication.

I am unable to create tables or create databases. How do I grant the permissions for the users logged in as Windows Authentication to be able to create tables / databases?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 0):

- In the Object Explorer look for the Security Folder at the top level.
- Then under logins right click and choose properties of the user in question.
- Grant them further access.